What is the significance of the differing shapes of the Medici Arms in the Palazzo Medici Riccardi courtyard?
I recently visited the Palazzo Medici Riccardi in Florence, which features an inner courtyard displaying four different versions of the Medici arms. I am curious about the significance of the shapes and designs of these arms.
I understand that the number of "balls" might relate to different members of the Medici family, but I would like to know more about the historical and symbolic meanings behind these variations. What do the different designs represent?


Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). At a minimum, all questions should explain why Wikipedia is insufficient.

@MCW : Sometimes it's obvious that the question is poorly researched and that Wikipedia could answer it, but sometimes it's obvious that Wikipedia doesn't, even before looking. Although well intended, asking to document previous research in those questions - and specially in the well formulated ones from new users -  is not very helpful nor in the spirit of "kindness" of the code of conduct.

Searching Wikipedia or other easily available sources just inform that the Medici coat of arms is made of six balls - one blue and six red - but it doesn't explain why sometimes there is a seventh one or why the shape of the coat of arms changes.

The point of asking for evidence of research is not merely to say "check Wikipedia". In this case it is clear that the OP did research, but didn't share the evidence. For starters, where are those images from? Don't make me search when you already have.

@Pere - Its pretty obvious to me that OP in fact has done some research that they aren't sharing, because they admitted they "understand that the number of balls might relate to different members of the Medici family". That certianly isn't obvious to me. How did they come to that understanding? Knowing that would be a great start for further research, but its presently left a mystery, for all our users to waste their own time solving.

Its possible they even got that info from this related question.

As I say to my grad students "I've said it before, and I'll say it again, some redundancy is good." :) :)

For information, the images are taken by me - as I mention, I recently visited Palazzo Medici Riccardi.  I did already look at other similar questions on this StackExchange.  I have read several descriptions of what the balls might signify, coins, pawn broker balls, pills, blood oranges, shield dents - I am interested in the significance of the different "sheild" shapes?

@Pere - probably an issue that should be addressed in meta.  I feel strongly that every question should be supported by research.  Both when the question shows an absence of research and in cases like this one where the OP may have done research, but has not shared, and therefore forces us to repeat the preliminary research. I welcome any suggestions about how to make the comment more friendly.
